# Does dynatables have to render all the data to an html table? Isn't that really slow for large datasets? How do we workaround it?

Tags: javascript, html, json, dynatable

I have a dataset with over 35k rows (filesize = 20mb) loaded as a Javascript Object. I want to render it via Dynatables. The process is really slow and locks up my browser. I guess it's because Dynatables renders everything into an html table.

I want to only load the data that is supposed to be displayed and update the table when the user paginates. How do I do that when I have my dataset as a local variable?

```
        tabCont.dynatable({
        table: {
          defaultColumnIdStyle: 'camelCase',
          headRowSelector: 'thead tr:first-child'
        },
        features: {
          pushState: false
        },
        dataset: {
          records: data,
          perPageDefault: 5,
          perPageOptions: [5,10,20,50,100]
        }
      });
```